# How do I display the last person that edited content instead of the original author?

Tags: views, 8

On the page `/admin/content`, there is a column for Author. We have a lot of people editing our content, so the original author isn't all that important. I want to change it to show the last person that edited the content, which I believe is stored in the revision of that content. How can I modify the view to show that? Alternatively, is there a hook I can implement in a custom module to do this?

I've checked out a couple other questions like [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178312/name-of-last-person-who-modified-node-display-suite) and [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171458/change-content-author-to-the-last-editor), but they weren't much help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding a relationship of `user (content revision)` & `Content (Content revision)` proved to be fruitless.

#### Ok, time for plan B

Using **[Views field view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)** we'll create a revision view, add revision user as field and then insert this view as field on the content view.

1) Create a new view

- Show: Content Revision
- Checkmark Create a block
- Items per block: 1

[image]

2) Add a contextual filter

- Originally I tried with Revision ID, but there is a bug, this contextual filter does not work.
- So instead use ID (which is the node id)

[image]

- When filter not available, `hide view`

[image]

3)

- Remove the changed & title fields
- Add `Revision User`

[image]

4) Add a Sort of `Changed`

[image]

- Select Descending sort

[image]

5) <kbd>Save</kbd> your view

---

Now go to the Content View (/admin/structure/views/view/content)

1) Add field of `ID`

[image]

- Checkmark, exclude from display

[image]

2) Add field `View`

[image]

- Select the view you just created and for contextual filter use `{{ fields.nid }}`

[image]

and that's it!

Comment: This worked out really nicely, thank you! I would have never guess there would be this many steps involved and I appreciate your screenshots. One question: the value appears empty for those pieces of content that were just created and not edited yet. Is there a way to fall back to the value of the original creator when there are no revisions?

Comment: And there are some others where there is a recent revision by a non-anonymous user, but it still shows up empty in the new column.

Comment: Actually, just removing the filter restriction on published content seems to do it. Although I am seeing a weird "off by one" issue in the view, where the last person to edit it appears exactly one row below where they should be. Any reason why that might be?

Comment: Final update: I had to switch `{{ fields.nid }}` to `{{ raw_fields.nid }}` to fix the "off by one" issue. Thanks again, accepting as the answer.

Comment: `the value appears empty for those pieces of content that were just created and not edited yet. Is there a way to fall back to the value of the original creator` @KimberlyW Add author as field, make sure field is arranged above the view field. Hide the author field if you like and then go to view field, scroll down a bit and click for no results behavior, click on replacement patterns and put the pattern for the author.